# What is the title of this DC comics book?

Tags: dc

I've seen in the Batman sold by Moleskine diary.
Which issues the scenes?

[image]

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it was a piece of "concept art" from the Dark Knight film rather than a comic in its own right.

Comment: Looks like the scene of Harvey Dent captured by Joker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Richard stated, it's immediately recognisable as the scene from the DarkKnight.

The only other guarantees I can make is that this does not occur in the first 20 issues of any Gotham-related New52 title (including Batman), as I've read them all.